# Is there a Twitter debugger like the one in Facebook or Google?

Tags: twitter, markup

Is there a markup debugging tool for Twitter like the ones on Facebook or Google?

- Facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
- Google data testing tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Please read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is not an off-topic question

Comment: still a good question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I suppose this is what you are looking for:

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator (Thanks to [MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426743/md-sahib-bin-mahboob) for the updated link)

(previously at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator)

Comment: Link is broken...

Comment: It is now located at : https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: Thanks for the updated link, answer updated.

Comment: These all require a registered account, are there no tools that are open to the public?